# Selecting different body parts of any Rig

Tags: animation

In viewport I can drag and rotate, position, scale any part of the rig armature, but only FK-RibCage is "officially" selected no matter what I select (written in top left corner of the picture, yellow letters) and I can see only it's location, rotation, scale values (Right side of the picture, yellow bars).

I'm using Blender 3.3.1 LTS on Mac Monterey 12.4

[image: right hand selected in viewport but Transform is showing coordinates for FK-RibCage]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean by *"different body part stays printed in the top left corner and in the Item -> Transform drop down menu"*? Which parts? What do you want to do? What is in the top left corner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I couldn't tweak Loc. Rot. and Scale numbers in the panel on the right (the one that activates when you press N) of the rig part that I've selected in the viewport. No matter what part I selected in the viewport it would keep showing values for a different part (usually FK-RibCage). Like I wrote, I could select, and move the desired body part in viewport and even key it, but I couldn't see the numeric values for it's Loc. Rot. and Scale and therefore couldn't tweak by changing these numbers.

Turns out that changing my selection from select box or select lasso to TWEAK solves this issue. I now get values for the part of the rig that I've selected and the correct name displays in the top left corner of the viewport as well.

Hope I made my problem understandable, don't know how better to describe it beyond this. Unfortunately server won't let me add picture today.

Would be curious to know if this is a feature or a bug. I don't see a reason why you couldn't use select box or lasso to "fully" select a part of a Rig, But maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: This sounds like a bug. I usually use the *Lasso* to select bones because on my computer the selection takes longer and longer over time when I use click or *Box Select*. It's probably also a bug or a graphic driver issue. If I restart Blender then it works fine again for some time.

Comment: Your'e probably right. To be honest I'm using pretty underpowered MacBook for Blender as I wait for my new PC to arrive. Processor: 2,3 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5, with 16GB RAM and Intel Iris Plus Graphics 640 1536 MB graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

Am not really sure of what is exactly the problem, but I assume it would be great if you can select other parts of the rig right?

Then with your rig selected in the scene hierarchy, go in the properties panel, and then go to the rig part. Try using different type of viewport display settings.

[image: Rig viewport display settings]

You can also check if some bones aren't hidden in your scene hierarchy.

Please provide more info about your problem if it is not solved :)